# Processing form values for each day of week

Tags: php, form

I am using PHP, and I am getting the value back from the form. Since I am working with time, I have an array by (1 x 4) x 7, and I feel like I could do a better job at it. I just don't know exactly how should I approach the problem

```
$schedule = array(
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['mon'][1]) - strtotime($_POST['mon'][0])) / 3600, 2),
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['mon'][3]) - strtotime($_POST['mon'][2])) / 3600, 2),

    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['tue'][1]) - strtotime($_POST['tue'][0])) / 3600, 2),
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['tue'][3]) - strtotime($_POST['tue'][2])) / 3600, 2),

    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['wed'][1]) - strtotime($_POST['wed'][0])) / 3600, 2),
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['wed'][3]) - strtotime($_POST['wed'][2])) / 3600, 2),

    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['thu'][1]) - strtotime($_POST['thu'][0])) / 3600, 2),
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['thu'][3]) - strtotime($_POST['thu'][2])) / 3600, 2),

    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['fri'][1]) - strtotime($_POST['fri'][0])) / 3600, 2),
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['fri'][3]) - strtotime($_POST['fri'][2])) / 3600, 2),

    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['sat'][1]) - strtotime($_POST['sat'][0])) / 3600, 2),
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['sat'][3]) - strtotime($_POST['sat'][2])) / 3600, 2),

    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['sun'][1]) - strtotime($_POST['sun'][0])) / 3600, 2),
    round(abs(strtotime($_POST['sun'][3]) - strtotime($_POST['sun'][2])) / 3600, 2),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, every time you see a repeated code, you could think of a loop.

if I am not mistaken, only a weekday is changed, so it could be used to form the loop:

```
$schedule = [];
$weekdays = ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun'];
foreach ($weekdays as $day)
{
    $schedule[] = round(abs(strtotime($_POST[$day][1]) - strtotime($_POST[$day][0])) / 3600, 2),
    $schedule[] = round(abs(strtotime($_POST[$day][3]) - strtotime($_POST[$day][2])) / 3600, 2),
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Managed to remove a lot of code that were similar by at least 40%!